# How to get central points for polygons, necessarily in these polygons (R,sp)

Tags: r, gis, r-sp

How to get central points for polygons that would fall necessarily in those  polygons? Just getting the centroid will fall outside the polygon for many not convex polygons.

Ideally the polygons would be SpatialPolygons in R and the central points would also be returned as an sp object.

Comment: What are your criteria for 'central point' if the centroid isn't what you want? Not being difficult, but the centroid is by definition the centre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetCentralPoints` from the [spatDataManagement package](https://bitbucket.org/cmbce/r-package-spatdatamanagement).
That is derived from [this answer](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Better-label-placement-for-polygons-td7580550.html) somewhere else on the web.

Executing the example would return:

```
plot(woods[1:5,])
# the centroids
plot(GetCentroids(woods[1:5,]),add=T)
# the central points guaranteed to be in the polygons
plot(GetCentralPoints(woods[1:5,]),add=T,col="blue")
legend("bottomright",legend=c("Centroids","Central points"),col=c("black","blue"),pch="+")
```

You get (note the bottom polygon)

[image]